# Framework for non-web Ruby project

Tags: ruby, frameworks

I'm looking for a simple Ruby framework for a **non-web** project. I'm very familiar with Rails, so when I write pure Ruby I miss:

- The different environments (`development, test, production`)
- The console `rails c`
- And many other utilities provided by rake or rails

I know I can require ActiveSupport and friends, but it's not what I need. It's mostly the development framework that I miss.

One thing I investigated is to do my project as a gem (even if I don't need a gem at the end). Using jeweler for instance provides versioning. I'm sure there are better ways but I can't find any. What would you use ?

Comment: Do you need a database backend for your project?

Comment: Unless you're not sure what you want, can you describe a little more about what you want? For example, do you want something where you can say `foo generate classname` and it'll create `lib/application/classname.rb` and `test/tc_classname.rb` and create an empty class and an empty TestCase?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alright, that is somewhat of a three-part question. A *threstion*, or triesti... actually that doesn't work. *Threstion* it is then.

One thing to understand about Rails is that it *isn't* magical. It's code, written by mortal humans who have faults (such as oversized-egos) but who are also  *incredibly damn smart*. Therefore, we can understand it after perhaps a little bit of studying their work.

**1. Rails environments are lovely**

The code behind the Rails environment management is actually quite simple. You have a default environment which is set to `development` by [this line in `railties/lib/rails/commands/server.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/railties/lib/rails/commands/server.rb#L53-55). You could do much the same thing in your application. Run a bit of initialization code that defines `YourAwesomeThing.environment = ENV["AWESOME_ENV"] || "development"`. Then it's a matter of requiring `config/environments/#{YourAwesomeThing.environment}.rb` where you need it. Then it's a matter of having configuration in those files that modify how your library works depending on the environment.

I couldn't find the line that does that in `3-1-stable` (it's gone walkies), so [here's one that I think does it in the `3-0-stable` branch.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L53).

As for the lovely methods such as `Rails.env.production?`, they are provided by the `ActiveSupport::StringInquirer` class.

**2. Rails console is the Second Coming**

I think `rails console` is amazing. I don't want to create a new file just to manually test some code like I would have done back in the Black Days of PHP. I can jump into the console and try it out there and then type `exit` when I'm done. *Amazing*. I think Rails developers don't appreciate the console nearly enough.

Anyway, this is just an `irb` session that has the Rails environment loaded before it! I'll restate it again: Rails is *not magical*. If you typed `irb` and then inside that irb session typed `require 'config/environment'` you would get (at least as far as I am aware...) an identical thing to the Rails console!

This is due to the magic that goes on in the initialization part of Rails which is *almost magic, but not* and I've explained it in the [Initialization Guide Which Will Be Finished And Updated For Rails 3.1 Real Soon I Promise Cross My Heart And Hope to Die If Only I Had The Time](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html)!

You could probably learn a lot by reading that text seemingly of a similar length to a book written by George R. R. Martin or Robert Jordan. I definitely learned a lot writing it!

**3. The Others**

This is where I falter. What other utilities do you need from Rake / Rails? It's all *there*, you just need to pick out the parts you need which is actually quite simple... but I can't tell you how to do that unless you go ahead and paint those targets.

---

Anyway, this is the kind of question that is exciting for me to answer. Thanks for giving me that bit of entertainment :)

**Edit**

I just noticed the BONUS fourth question at the end of your question. What would be the point of versioning your project? Why not use a version control system such as Git to do this and just `git tag` versions as you see fit? I think that would make the most sense.

Comment: There are answers of all types, but ones like this create their own category :)

Comment: I don't like this answer - I don't like reinventing the wheel. Is there anything ready to use for non-web applications?

Comment: I also don't like this "answer", if you can even call it that. The question was not calling for an explanation of how Rails works it's "magic/not-magic", it was asking about the existence of a framework for NON-WEB ruby projects.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Rails goal as a web framework is to let you mostly forget about the low-level details of a web based application (interacting with a web server, a database, etc.) and provide you with high-level abstractions which allow you to concentrate yourself on the actual job: Getting your application done.

There is such a huge diversity of non-web applications, that it is simply **impossible** to have a framework that "makes them all".

It is useful to understand what a framework is, and why and when you should use it.

Let's say you would have to build a dog house. You would buy some wood, nails and a hammer to build it the way you want *from scratch*, or you could go to Walmart and buy a DIY doghouse kit.
You will get a manual with detailed instructions on how to build your dog's "dream doghouse", and you will get it faster done than when making it from scratch, but you will be limited to the wood that comes with it and may be forced to use their nails or screws, and in some cases you would also need to buy a special screw driver.

The DIY kit is your framework. Some smart guys already provided you with the basic tools of making your doghouse, you only had to figure out (or not, if you had a manual) how to do it given their "framework".

Now, let's say you would build a skyscraper. The materials, tools and conventions (the framework) used would probably not be the same as they would when building a doghouse, and it would be over-kill to use a "skyscraper framework" to build a doghouse.

You wouldn't write Twitter client with the same set of tools and conventions as you would when writing a banking application with a billion concurrent users.

Rails is just *one* framework which provides you with a set of many, many good (and useful) conventions to write a web application, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it's *the ultimate way* to go. You can choose another framework, and maybe you will like the conventions for writing your application even more than the ones provided by Rails; or you could write all from scratch which would not limit you to what is provided by a specific framework and maybe make it even better.

To answer your question: Think of what you want to write and don't let yourself be narrowed down by the set of tools and conventions provided by a framework, as they will surely be if you choose this path.

Buy yourself some books about Design Patterns and read some great software, and then you may understand why the authors did not choose an application framework. Indeed, they've developed their own conventions and defined the behavior of what it should do; and once again, the "Rails way" isn't the only way, which doesn't make it the bad way. :)

I would appreciate constructive criticism as I really tried to provide a good answer.

Comment: I am not sure that this actually answers the question, sorry :( I think he was interested in learning how the parts of Rails works so that he could borrow ideas and put them to work in his own thing. Aside from that, this is a very well-written answer! We need more like it on SO.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, Ryan. I realize my answer is only a half-answer to the original question, but I don't consider it entirely off-topic.

Comment: I've never seen a non-trivial application development situation that wouldn't benefit from *some* sort of framework. A framework helps make it clear where the various pieces go and eases maintenance. If you want to roll your own framework, you certainly can, but usually it's less effort to use something that (hopefully) many people smarter than you already put the effort into creating -- and documenting.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Monkeybars](http://monkeybars.org)? It's a Rails-inspired MVC framework that runs on top of JRuby and Swing to build desktop applications. I like it a lot.