# What non-trivial Ruby applications exist?

Tags: ruby

What publicly available open source Ruby applications (not frameworks) exist apart from web applications?

This question is similar to [Ruby off the rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150638/ruby-off-the-rails) , except that's about anecdotes of what Ruby applications they've created, which aren't necessarily publicly available.

These applications should be non-trivial: ideally multiple committers, with well-designed code to handle the complexity of their task.

One example would be the [Metasploit Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasploit_Project).

Background: Asking in response to [Framework for non-web Ruby project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114521/framework-for-non-web-ruby-project), where I realised that I haven't seen any examples of Ruby applications that aren't one-person projects.

Comment: @Vache: OPs haven't had the ability to mark a question as community wiki for ages.

Comment: Oh I didn't know. How do you make one then?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/).  This Ruby project is becoming the de-facto tool for managing cloud architectures.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [hackety hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hackety_Hack)?  Non-trivial, but you will find plenty of interesting ideas in the source code if you're adventurous. Being written by _why, it's pretty fanciful.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of Mac OS X applications written in Ruby-Cocoa (LimeChat is an example; I think Colloquy used to be, though its website implies that that may have changed).

As far as not seeing Ruby projects by more than one person...huh? True, most open-source Ruby development these days seems to be in the Rails world, but within that community there are lots of huge projects with many developers.

You might ask this question on the Ruby mailing list; you'll almost certainly get more good answers.

Comment: "but within that community there are lots of huge projects with many developers." - do you mean by "that community" the Rails community, or the non-Rails Ruby community? The former won't be of much help to the OP of the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114521/framework-for-non-web-ruby-project question.

Comment: I meant the former. And I was answering *your* question, not the other one. I see no reason to spread questions over multiple pages.